# Save the sqlite file to phone storage in react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

I am trying to save SQLite file to the phone storage because the user deletes or reinstalls the app then the user will lost the previous data of the app.
So is there any way to save data to phone storage for persisting SQLite file?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What is your problem with copying a file?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How can users copy that files before they remove the app?

Comment: You should add a copy posibility to your app. For the rest there is no difference with copying any other file.

Comment: Thank you.
Let me try with that way.